# Facing ^M issue in Git

Tags: git

While pushing from my local workstation (Windows) to the remote repository(RHEL 6) , I can see all the files are having ^M characters.

I have tried the below options but unfortunately with no luck.

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

as well as

```
git config core.autocrlf input
```

I tried editing the gitconfig file directly also but still the issue persists.

Comment: Have you made a commit after setting this option locally?

Comment: @raina77ow : Yes, I have made a commit (and pushed to remote repo) after trying out the options but still the problem persists.